# How to extract a particular Key-Value Tag from ec2 describe-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq

I've got the following from describe-instances:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Key": "Name",
                            "Value": "yyyyy"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "budget_cluster",
                            "Value": "zzzzz"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "poc",
                            "Value": "aaaaaaa"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For each instance, I would like to extract the PublicDnsName and the value of the "budget_cluster" tag key. How to do this either with `ec2 describe-instances` or with `jq` ?

Comment: The sample JSON you provided is incomplete.  Please amend your post to include a minimalist piece of valid JSON that is sufficient for the purpose.

Comment: Right. It's not valid json. But it contains enough info for someone who knows ec2 and jq to give a workable solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modifying Frédéric's answer:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query \
   'Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicDnsName, Tags[?Key==`budget_cluster`].Value | [0]]'
```

Would produce:

```
ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com zzzzz
ec2-bbbbb.amazonaws.com yyyyy
```

I've changed the output to text, which removes as much formatting as possible and selected the individual tag value with `| [0]` since there will only ever be one per instance anyway. Finally, I removed the `[]` at the end so that the resulting list isn't flattened. That way in text output each entry will be on its own line.

You can also make this more robust by only selecting instances that actually have that tag. You could do so with further modifications to the `--query` parameter, but it is better in this case to use the `--filters` parameter since it does service-side filtering. Specifically you want the `tag-key` filter: `--filters "Name=tag-key,Values=budget_cluster"`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text \
    --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=budget_cluster" --query \
   'Reservations[].Instances[?Tags[?Key==`budget_cluster`]].[PublicDnsName, Tags[?Key==`budget_cluster`].Value | [0]]'
```

Would still produce:

```
ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com zzzzz
ec2-bbbbb.amazonaws.com yyyyy
```

But over the wire you would only be getting the instances you care about, thus saving money on bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

Using jq 1.5 or later, the simplest approach is to use `from_entries`.

After a minimal fix of the illustrative input, the following invocation:

```
$ jq '.Reservations[]
      | .Instances[]
      | [.PublicDnsName, (.Tags|from_entries|.budget_cluster)]' input.json
```

produces:

```
[
  "ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com",
  "zzzzz"
]
```

If you do not have jq 1.5 or later, the following should work:

```
$ jq1.4 '.Reservations[]
| .Instances[]
| [.PublicDnsName, (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="budget_cluster") | .Value)]' input.json
```

Comment: Neither this nor my fast and thoughtless attempts at modifying it work. They produce: `jq: error: Cannot use null as object key
jq: error: Cannot use null as object key`

Comment: The solution as given assumes you have jq 1.5 or later (1.5 being the most recent official release). See update to posting.

Comment: your jq1.4 solutions works, putting it into an array (each couplet embraced by square brackets.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @peak is great and I keep learning from him on the `jq` part but again you can achieve quite a lot from the AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query \
   'Reservations[].Instances[].{PublicDnsName:PublicDnsName, Budget:Tags[?Key==`budget_cluster`].Value}'
```

would produce

```
[
    {
        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com",
        "Budget": [
                "zzzz",
        ]
    }
]
```

If you do not want to make a new strict JSon out of it, just take the values

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query \
   'Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicDnsName, Tags[?Key==`budget_cluster`].Value][]'
```

will produce

```
[
    "ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com",
    [
        "zzzz"
    ]
]
```

Comment: This works as you say. But what I'm looking for is to extract just the PublicDNSName and the value of the Budget key, without any other text.

Comment: adding example without JSon key, this just returns an array then and not a JSon

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what I'm looking for is just a simple: `"ec2.." "zzz"`

Comment: if you want pure text, change the output; there are 3 possible output format : `text`, `table` and `json` - most of the time default is json and what you want - in your case change the output to text and you get what you want. also Jordon complemented my answer