# AWS CLI: How to achieve certain output format for describe-instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to pull a list of all of our instances formatted like so:

`Tag:Name.Value instance-id private-ip-address`

This is the command I'm using:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

And this is what I'm getting as output:

```
instance-id private-ip-address
tag:name.value
```

Even though I've got the Tag bit before everything else, it still lists on a new line below the corresponding ID/IP.

Any way to fix this? Also any way to retrieve a format like this:

`Tag:name.value,instance-id,private-ip-address`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found `jq` to be the most flexible method for working with the AWS CLI.

The following takes input from `describe-instances` and pipes it into `jq`.  `jq` extracts the bits you're interested in and outputs it in the CSV format you specified.

**CLI**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  |jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]| . as $i | [($i.Tags|from_entries|.Name)?, $i.InstanceId, $i.PrivateIpAddress] |@csv'
```

**Output**

> "ac02-01","i-0123456789ABCDEF","10.0.0.214"

**References**

[How to extract a particular Key-Value Tag from ec2 describe-instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902587/how-to-extract-a-particular-key-value-tag-from-ec2-describe-instances)

Comment: This is awesome. A problem I'm now experiencing, however, is that `jq` is failing after a short list, with the error: "Cannot iterate over null (null)"

Comment: Do you have instances without tags?

Comment: Mmm..that *may* be a possibility. I'm not certain, tho. We have over 400 instances and I haven't seen all of them. Any sort of magic for "tag if tag exists?" Haha.

Comment: @Mike This can be done without `jq` command, please have a look at my answer

Comment: Added a `?` after the Tags piece which will skip over nulls

Comment: Hey kenlukas, that is awesome. Gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

**CLI**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],InstanceId, PrivateIpAddress][]]' --output text | sed 's/\t/,/g'
```

It can be achieved without using `jq` just with aws cli query syntax.

You need to "flatten" tag name with other fields with `[]` operator. The output will be splitted by tab, so `sed 's/\t/,/g'` to replace tab with comma.

*Note: on Macs `sed 's/\t/,/g'` may not work as `\t` is not recognized as Tab character. To insert tab, press `Ctrl+V` and then `Tab`*

Comment: Awesome. This did the trick. Any way to format to CSV/comma separated items?

Comment: @Mike I updated the answer. Unfortunetely, we have to replace tabs with commas using `sed`